# Show that function is in L^2

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I'm going through a paper and I came across the following statement:

> Given $\mathbf{q}_h \in \mathbf{V}_h(\Omega)$ we have to show that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{q}_h$ is well defined and in $L^2(\Omega)$. In other words we have to find $z_h \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that:
>
> $\int_\Omega \mathbf{q}_h\cdot\nabla \varphi d\Omega = -\int_\Omega z_h\varphi d\Omega$, $\varphi\in D(\Omega)$

Where does that "in other words" equation come from? It must somehow equivalent to showing:

$\left(\int_\Omega (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{q}_h)^2 d\Omega\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty$

which is the textbook definition of $L^2$, but it's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: What's the space $V_h$?

Comment: Oops should have defined that. $V^h$ is the space of functions that are polynomials over each element of a mesh (not necessarily continuous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point is that $\nabla \cdot q_h$ is not the classical divergence, as it is not defined. It's the weak divergence, or the divergence of the distribution $q_h$. It's always defined as a distribution, but this distribution is not necessary a $L^2$ function (it could even be not a classical function, like a Dirac).

As $q_h$ is $L^1_{loc}$, $q_h$ has a weak divergence in $L^2$ if there exists a function $z_h \in L^2$ such that

$$\forall \varphi \in D,\ \int_{\Omega} z_h \varphi dx = - \int_{\Omega} q_h \nabla\cdot\varphi dx$$

$z_h$ is then called the weak divergence of $q_h$, and we note $\nabla\cdot q_h := z_h$

Note that if $q_h$ has a classical divergence, the weak and the classical divergence are the same function

Comment: That makes sense, and then as @gerw pointed out I need to show that $z_h\in L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This equation is the derivative of the weak divergence. If you have found $z_h$ satisfying this equation, you have to check $z_h \in L^2(\Omega)$ and this amounts to check $$\int_\Omega z_h^2 \mathrm{d}x < \infty.$$